# C# Animation Freezes the program

Tags: c#, winforms, animation

For some reason, This freezes the program:

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x = 1;
    var frame1 = pictureBox2.BackgroundImage;
    var frame2 = pictureBox3.BackgroundImage;
    while(x < 2)
    {
        pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = frame1;
        pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = frame2;
    }
}
```

why?
`pictureBox2` contains the first frame and `pictureBox3` contains the second.
`pictureBox1` contains the 'animation'. (as seen in code)

EDIT: I don't want it to animate **ONCE**, I want it to animate **FOREVER.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way...

Mark your Shown() event with `async`, then use `await Task.Delay()` between frames:

```
    private async void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool first = true;
        var frame1 = pictureBox2.BackgroundImage;
        var frame2 = pictureBox3.BackgroundImage;
        while (true)
        {
            pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = first ? frame1 : frame2;
            first = !first;
            await Task.Delay(500); // 1/2 second delay <-- set it to your desired delay between frames
        }
    }
```

---------- Edit ----------

An alternate approach using a Timer and an IEnumerator.  This would be a good way to go if you had more than just two frames:

```
    private IEnumerator<Image> frames;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmr;

    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Image> lstFrames = new List<Image>();
        lstFrames.Add(pictureBox2.BackgroundImage);
        lstFrames.Add(pictureBox3.BackgroundImage);
        lstFrames.Add(pictureBox4.BackgroundImage);
        // etc...
        frames = lstFrames.GetEnumerator();
        DisplayNextFrame();

        tmr = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        tmr.Interval = 500;
        tmr.Tick += Tmr_Tick;
        tmr.Start();
    }

    private void Tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayNextFrame();
    }

    private void DisplayNextFrame()
    {
        if (!frames.MoveNext())
        {
            frames.Reset();
            frames.MoveNext();
        }
        pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = frames.Current;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

*In your case, the value of `x` is always `1` and that is why the while loop keep iterating and the program goes in an infinite loop.*

Solution:

You should use [`BackgroundWorker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to run the code as an `Asynchronous`

Insert a new `BackgroundWorker` into your form.

Insert your function into `DoWork` event.

```
private void bWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)  
{  
    var frame1;
    var frame2;

    if (pictureBox2.InvokeRequired) { pictureBox2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { frame1 = pictureBox2.BackgroundImage; }); } else { frame1 = pictureBox2.BackgroundImage; }
    if (pictureBox3.InvokeRequired) { pictureBox3.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { frame2 = pictureBox3.BackgroundImage; }); } else { frame2 = pictureBox3.BackgroundImage; }

    while (true)
    {
        if (pictureBox1.InvokeRequired) { pictureBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = frame1; }); } else { pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = frame1; }
        if (pictureBox1.InvokeRequired) { pictureBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = frame2; }); } else { pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = frame2; }
    }
}
```

Now, Start running `BackgroundWorker`.

```
bWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: OP said animation, which must keep running. `if` will stop it after just changing 2 frames.

Comment: @VishalSuthar, I guess the OP wants the loop to run forever so I guess your answer won't help a lot. He needs to unblock the thread to be able to run background tasks which allow to refresh the pictures to be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Create a parallel thread for your animiation:

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //create parallel thread
    Thread animationThread = new Thread(Animation);
    animationThread.Start();
}

//create a new method for animation to run on a parallel thread
private void Animation()
{
    int x = 1;
    var frame1 = pictureBox1.Image;
    var frame2 = pictureBox2.Image;
    while (x < 2)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => pictureBox3.Image = frame1));
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => pictureBox3.Refresh()));
        Thread.Sleep(100); //you must keep a dealy other wise it will consume too much processing
        this.Invoke(new Action(() =>  pictureBox3.Image = frame2));
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => pictureBox3.Refresh()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop runs forever and never terminates.

There's no termination clause for the `while (x < 2)` loop hence your program freezes; `x` is always smaller than 2. If you don't allow the application to *breath* it freezes. Try this:

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var frame1 = pictureBox2.BackgroundImage;
    var frame2 = pictureBox3.BackgroundImage;
    while(true)
    {
        pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = frame1;
        Application.DoEvents(); // give the thread room to run background tasks

        pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = frame2;
        Application.DoEvents(); // give the thread room to run background tasks
    }
}
```

[DoEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx)() is just one option, maybe not the best for your case. You're probably better off writing a proper timer which switches between the two images ever 40 milliseconds or whatever your animation speed is supposed to be.

Comment: yeah ok. that doesn't help me

Comment: Your loop `while(x < 2)` runs forever. There's no termination clause hence your program freezes. `x` is always smaller than 2.

Comment: That is not an answer. Because it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: The OP asked "Why?" - not "How to solve the problem?" See updated answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add some time delays between the frame1 and frame2 inside while loop to see the animation work.

Comment: It will still block the UI because its running on the UI thread.